# Mention "users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 5 minutes" in "Privileges"

Tags: feature-request, privileges

When users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 5 minutes, then why is it not listed in the list of "Privileges" in the Privileges Page?

I request that this be made available in the list.

Comment: P.S. You should really remove that fake website from your profile as it goes to a parked advertising page. If you don't have a website, don't fill out the field.

Comment: @animuson Okay - I did that just to get the "Autobiographer" Badge.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar Next time, use [example.com](http://www.iana.org/domains/example/), that's what it's for.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Okay, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a privilege, but that limit could be mentioned on the "[create posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts)" privilege page.

I guess it is not mentioned to avoid editing the privilege page every time the limit is changed. It doesn't seem that limit is changed so frequently, and maybe the sentence describing it could be more generic, such as the following one:

> Users can post questions independently from the reputation they have, but new users (currently, users with a reputation lower than 125) have a restriction on the number of questions asked in the short time (currently, not more than a question every 5 minutes).

Answer (score 3):

It feels more like a constraint than a privilege to me...

Comment: *Not* having to wait for 5 min is a privilege though. You can see everything both ways.

Comment: Formulated that way, I have no choice but to agree. I was being probably just being overly concerned with semantics ....

Comment: One of our current privileges is called [remove new user restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user).

Comment: Right; I was thinking it could be described as, "post more often than once per five minutes".